# laravel assign routes to multiple middleware groups

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Can I assign routes to multiple middleware groups?:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'custom'], function() {
    Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup');
});
```

However I do not want to combine both middlewares in one group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'custom'], function() {
    Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup');
});
```

EDIT:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['custom']], function () {
        Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup');
        });
    });
```

won't work for my case since I want to have some routes in the the first group that are not in the second and vice versa.

Is it possible to do it using variables?

```
$lookupRoute = Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
            ??? $lookupRoute ??? 
        });

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'custom'], function() {
            ??? $lookupRoute ??? 
        });
```

Comment: some condition to apply middlewares or something?

Comment: You can assign middleware directly to a route if you need to, but I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish and why `middleware => [..., ...]` won't work for you.

Comment: @TimLewis Because I have many possible combinations of middlewares and I try to avoid to create separate groups for each of the possible combinations. I do currently assign them per each single route. But having groups would make it easier to reason which routes are used by specific middleware (e.g. I would be able to instantly see which routes use a logging middleware)

Comment: I don't think groups is the way to approach this then, unless you're prepared to make a group for each combination. I say this because even If you put the same route in multiple places, it only uses one of them, either the first or the last, I don't remember, to avoid route conflicts in the case of wildcard/parameterized routes.

Comment: You can put `prefix` inside the route group array, because one url will take the route which came first, you know you can give the different route name also in the prefix array as `as`

Comment: @Vikash I did not really understand. I think this would only allow me to have the routes prefix1/route and prefix2/route point to the same controller. But it does not solve the problem that I want one route belonging to multiple independent groups